# CSV Helper AutoMap List object?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am currently trying to get my CSV Helper AutoMap class to write out column headers/values for a List<> property from my other Class. For some reason, the functionality for auto mapping doesn't recognize this property, so it never gets written to the end of my CSV file like I want it to. Any thoughts on how to do this? Does it have to be written to CSV manually? Please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT: My List<> also comes back as null for some reason here so it doesn't get written via auto mapping.

```
public class TemplateViewModelMap<TViewModel> : ClassMap<TViewModel> where TViewModel : class
{
    public TemplateViewModelMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        // Use Reflection to check property for complex object type to remove/ignore from ClassMap.
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(TViewModel).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            string fieldPropertyName = "Fields";

            if (property.Name.Equals(fieldPropertyName) == true)
            {
                MemberReferenceMap item = ReferenceMaps.Find(property);
                ReferenceMaps.Add(item);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically a `TViewModel` that demonstrates the problem?  See: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to map a class that has fields and not properties?  In that case you can set the configuration to `MemberTypes.Fields`.

```cs
void Main()
{   
    var fooList = new List<Foo>()
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "first" },
        new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "second" }
    };
    
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        MemberTypes = CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields
    };
    
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, config))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(fooList);
    }
    
}

public class Foo 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the CSV Helper to write a public virtual List<ObjectFieldViewModel> Fields as a property contained from my main class to write ClientViewModel. I would like it to add the headers/values as part of my full writeRecords() call, except it's not writing this object for some reason.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you are trying to do.  Can you add a simple example of the class and what you want the output to look like?